# How to set hadoop input format to NLineInputFormat?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to limit the number of lines each of the Mappers gets.
My code goes like this:

```
    package com.iathao.mapreduce;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;

    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
    import org.apache.regexp.RESyntaxException;

    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;

    public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, RESyntaxException {

    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: NewMaxTemperature <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
        job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.max.map.failures.percent", "100");
        // job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.map.max.attempts", "10");
        //NLineInputFormat. .setNumLinesPerSplit(job, 1);
        job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
```

At the last line in the sample (job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);) I get following error:

```
The method setInputFormatClass(Class<? extends InputFormat>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<NLineInputFormat>)
```

Did I somehow get the wrong NLineInputFormat class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing the old and the new API.

> *import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat;*
>   *import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;*

According to the "Hadoop : The Definitive Guide"

> *The new API is in the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce package (and subpackages). The old API can still be found in org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*

If you plan to use the new API, then use the NLineInputFormat from the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce package.

Comment: actually, the problem was that NLineInputFormat is not implemented in the new api for hadoop 0.20. bad luck than, I'm going to use old api now

Comment: 0.21 has the new API, but is not stable version. You can also download the code from trunk or 0.23 branch and build it on a Linux machine. Getting the code from trunk or 0.23 branch will give you access to a lot of new features. But trunk or 0.23 branch keep on changing and is not in a stable state once in a while.